# Volley Post Request Failure with Webservice URL

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a URL in my webservice that responds to the request:

`http://localhost:3000/setFavoriteSpecial/1/47/190/2` in my rails app that acts as a webservice with the method as:

```
def setFavoriteSpecial
        setFavoriteSpecial = "INSERT INTO androidchatterdatabase.users_saved_campaigns(usersId,campaignId,cityLocationId,timePeriod,savedDt)
                              VALUES(" + params[:user_id].to_s + "," + params[:campaign_id].to_s + "," + params[:metro_id].to_s + "," + params[:time_period].to_s + ", NOW())"

        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(setFavoriteSpecial)
    end
```

with route:

```
  match '/setFavoriteSpecial/:user_id/:campaign_id/:metro_id/:time_period', to: 'requests#setFavoriteSpecial', via: 'get'
```

to set a persons favorite special given the four input parameters. However the volley post request, passing in the correct parameters does not produce the insert that this method is intended, but simply errors out.

The request is as:

```
            String setFavoriteSpecial = "http://" + Global.getIpAddress() + ":3000/setFavoriteSpecial/";

            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, setFavoriteSpecial,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // response
                            Log.d("Response", response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // error
                            Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("user_id", LoggingIn.userId);
                    params.put("campaign_id", specialId);
                    params.put("metro_id", "190");
                    params.put("time_period", "3");

                    return params;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(postRequest);
```

The error is as:

```
 E/Volley﹕ [190] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://192.168.1.122:3000/setFavoriteSpecial/2//109/3
 D/Error.Response﹕ com.android.volley.ServerError
```

Why won't this setup for Volley work?

Comment: What errors? post your logCat messages :)

Comment: I'm in Android Studio not Eclipse

Comment: Ok the 404 or Not Found error message means that the client wasn´t able to communicate with a given server, mmmm probably you need the User Agent?

Comment: Since you are getting a 404 error, are you sure that you can reach http://192.168.1.122:3000/setFavoriteSpecial/2//109/3 ???

Comment: @Elenasys yes I can access it, notes there is a view missing though